# N is a normal subgroup of G if $aNa^{-1} \subset N $ for all $a ∈ G$. Prove that in that case, $aNa^{-1} = N $.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I said if N is a normal subgroup of G when $aNa^{-1} \subset N $ aN = Na as N is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Therefore $aNa^{-1} = Naa^{-1} $ and $aNa^{-1} = N $.

I would like to go with this proof but it looks too simple for now?

Comment: I am unable to follow your train of thought. Did you go from $aNa^{-1}\subseteq N$ to $aN=Na$? That implication isn't true. It is true if you put $\forall a$s in front of both claims, but you would have to *show* that. What, exactly, are you trying to prove anyway? That if $aNa^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $a$, then $aNa^{-1}=N$ for all $a$? This strikes me as very difficult to read.

Comment: I just meant aN = Na would be true as N is defined as a normal subgroup!

Comment: What's your definition of normal subgroup? What are you trying to prove?

Comment: Normal subgroup defined as $aNa^{-1} \subset N$.

Comment: It's defined as a subgroup for which $aNa^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $a$, yes. So the definition has $\subseteq$, not $=$ in it! Thus, $aNa^{-1}=N$ is *not* part of the definition of "normal subgroup" you are working with. You have to actually prove that property. And that *is* what you're trying to prove, no? That if $N$ is normal then we know $aNa^{-1}=N$ for all $a$ (not just $aNa^{-1}\subseteq N$)? Surely you can't assume the thing you're trying to prove in an argument?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed since $N\lhd G$ then for all $g\in G$ we have $N^g\subseteq N$. Now do this for $g^{-1}\in G$ so we see that $N^{g^{-1}}\subseteq N$ and therefore $$(N^{g^{-1}})^g\subseteq N^g$$ But what is $(N^{g^{-1}})^g$ then?

Comment: Does $N^g$ denote $gNg^{-1}$?

Comment: @angryavian either that or $g^{-1}Ng$, it doesn't really matter which!

Comment: @blue It does matter: $N^g=g^{-1} N g$, since it is a right action. If you want a left action of $G$ on the conjugates of $N$, then you take the other one $^gN=N^{g^{-1}} = g N g^{-1}$.

Comment: @LiorB-S Yes group theorists use that choice because it makes sense as a right action; it would be very weird to write a left action on the right. My comment was pointing out that it doesn't matter which choice of definition one uses; the reasoning in the answer works either way.

Comment: Weirdness is a matter of whether you are used to it or not. In any rate you can write $N^{g^{-1}}$.